# What is the best vbscript code to add decimal places to all numbers in a string?

Tags: vbscript

Example

G76 I0.4779 J270 K7 C90

X20 Y30

If a number begins with I J K C X Y and it doesn't have a decimal then add decimal.
Above example should look like:

G76 I0.4779 J270 K7. C90.

X20. Y30.

Purpose of this code is to convert CNC code for an older Fanuc OPC controller

Answer (score 2):

```
Set RegEx = New RegExp
RegEx.Global = True
RegEx.Pattern = "([IJKCXY]\d+)([^\.]|$)"
newVar = RegEx.Replace (oldString, "$1.$2")
```

Where oldString is the original string, and newVar is the string with the decimals added.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert(str)
    Set RegEx = New RegExp
    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.Pattern = "([IJKCXY]\d*\.?\d*)"
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(str)

    For Each Match in Matches
        if instr(Match.value, ".") = 0 then
            str = Replace(str, Match.value, Match.value & ".")
        end if
    Next
    convert = str
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

tloach still answer doesn't work

Waynes works but also puts a . after every occurrence of IJKCXY

I changed   if instr(Match.value, ".") = 0 then

To be like if instr(Match.value, ".") = 0 and len(Match.value) > 1 then